# How to split a string with an uniq substring in bash?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, split, grep

I have a string:

```
str="...AAA..."
```

I want to split it to 3 substring variables `sub1`, `sub2`, `sub3`. The string `AAA` is `sub2` and is an unique pattern which won't appear in `sub1` and `sub3`. And all the other characters were saved in `sub1` and `sub3`. Only one extreme situation is that `AAA` may appear at the end when `sub3` needs to be an empty string. How can I achieve this, maybe using `grep`, `sed` or `gawk`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `grep`, `sed`, or `awk`. Just use [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) with `%` and `#`:

```bash
str="ABCAAAXYZ"
sub2="AAA"

sub1="${str%${sub2}*}"
sub3="${str#*${sub2}}"

printf '%s\n' "$sub1" "$sub2" "$sub3"
```

```
ABC
AAA
XYZ
```

This works just the same with `str="ABCAAA"` or `str="AAAXYZ"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Perl one-liner in which you change the index (at the end of the line) to return different captured variables (`$m[0]`, `$m[1]`, `$m[2]`):

```
export str="ABCAAAXYZ"
export pattern='AAA' # or can be a regex, such as 'A{2,3}'

sub1=$( perl -le '@m = $ENV{str} =~ m{(.*?)($ENV{pattern})(.*)}; print $m[0];' )
sub2=$( perl -le '@m = $ENV{str} =~ m{(.*?)($ENV{pattern})(.*)}; print $m[1];' )
sub3=$( perl -le '@m = $ENV{str} =~ m{(.*?)($ENV{pattern})(.*)}; print $m[2];' )
echo $sub1 $sub2 $sub3
```

Prints:

```
ABC AAA XYZ
```

It also works as intended with `ABCAAA` and `AAAXYZ`.

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

`$ENV{str}` : environment (shell) variable `$str`.
`(.*?)` : any character repeated 0 or more times. `?` makes it non-greedy, so that the shortest match is captured.
`(.*)` : same, greedy, so that the longest match is captured.
All the parentheses are needed to capture the matches and assign them to the elements of array `@m`.
We then print elements of array `@m` (`$m[0]`, `$m[1]`, `$m[2]`), that is, the groups that are captured by parentheses.

**See also:**

- [`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
- [`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
- [`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Comment: Thanks for your editing and a new point of view.